# concat column values untill the second last valid transaction(non zero or not null)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concat transactions to its **second last valid trasaction**.
Suppose I have columns till 4th transaction and I want to generate a sequence like below output.
Note: Values in trans columns are categorical.

**Input Data**:

```
| Cust_id    | trans_1 | trans_2 | trans_3 | trans_4 |
|------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1000026037 | 'a'     | 'b'     | 'd'     |  NaN    | 
| 1000026048 | 'm'     | 'c'     |  NaN    |  NaN    |
| 1000026081 | 'x'     | 't'     | 'y'     |  NaN    |
| 1000026451 | 'r'     | 'p'     |  NaN    | 'u'     |
```

**Desired Output**:
`| Sequence |
|----------|
| 'a b'    |
| 'm'      |
| 'x t'    |
| 'r p'    |`

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? and where you are facing difficulty in logic. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This looks like a good question. I've been tasked by stackoverflow to recommend improvements to first-time questions.  I recommend capitalizing the first word of sentences ("...transaction.  Support I have...").    Also, the question is not very obvious to me.  Also, the word "till" is not a word; perhaps you meant the word "until" ?

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 Sorry...its until the second last transaction and mean while i dont want zero or nulls to be considered.

Comment: @LakshyaSrivastava 
I could concat all transaction col values using below code but not getting how to concat it except the last transaction value:

filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('trans')]
df['Sequence']= df[filter_col].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the transaction columns and get the data until second last nonzero and concatenate.

```
df.filter(regex='trans_')
  .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.nonzero()].iloc[:-1], axis=1)
  .add(' ')
  .sum(axis=1)
  .str.strip()
```

OR

```
df.filter(regex='trans_')
  .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.iloc[x.nonzero()].iloc[:-1]), axis=1)
```

**NOTE**

Ensure all zeros are integer zeros and not string zeros i.e `0` and not `'0'`

```
df = df.replace({'0': 0})
```

Comment: I have all categorical values in Trans_ columns

Comment: Type cast to str and comeback to categorical. You haven't mentioned this in the question.

Comment: I tried ur your code but getting error:
('sequence item 1: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index 0')

Actually I have NaN and replacing them with zero in my code and trying to concat strings

Comment: @SthitpragyanSahoo use the `df.fillna(0)` to ensure your dataset resembles what you have asked.

Comment: @SthitpragyanSahoo None of the `tans_` columns must have `NaN`. The error is because of the fact that `NaN` is considered `float` and cant be concatenated as a string.

Comment: @Vishnudev datatype of my column is object and its holding NaN .Then how should I go about this.

Comment: You should fix the problem at the source, where NaN is becoming a string may be because you are using astype(str) somewhere. For now you could use `df = df.replace({'NaN': 0})`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vishnudev. There was some issue in replacing NaNs.
df.replace(np.nan, 0) worked for me and now using the above code I am getting my output. Thanks:)